# Como hacer consulta a un archivo dbf desde c#

Tags: c#, dbase

estoy haciendo un API para trabajar con Adminpaq (tiene su base de datos en DBF) por lo que necesitamos subir archivos a este, pero sus campos no son autoincrementables, por lo que necesito obtener el ultimo registro, pero este demora mas de 1 min en hacer la consulta

```
public void UltimoRegistro()
        {
            OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection();
            Debug.WriteLine("entro a la llamada");
            cnn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=VFPOLEDB; Data Source = W:\Empresas\PRUEBAS\; Extended Properties=dBase 5.0";
            using (cnn)
            {
                string consulta = "SELECT ciddocum01 FROM MGW10008 ORDER BY CFECHA DESC";
                cnn.Open();
                new OleDbCommand("USE MGW10008 ORDER PRIMARYKEY SHARED IN 0", cnn).ExecuteNonQuery();
                //new OleDbCommand("GO BOTTOM", cnn).ExecuteReader();

                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(consulta, cnn))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            if (reader.Read())
                            {
                                Debug.WriteLine(reader.GetInt32(0));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (OleDbException ex)
                    {
                        oLog.Add(ex.Message.ToString());
                        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message, " error en lo headers");
                    }
                    cnn.Close();
                }

            }
        }
```

esta es la funcion con la que hago la consulta pero enserio que dura mas de 1 min. estoy utilizando indices para que dure menos pero al hacer la consulta asi, este recorre completamente todo el archivo.

Comment: Y porque no la ordenas al reves? no entiendo bien la problematica....

Comment: en una asigno mi consulta y en donde hago el new OleDbCommand es donde ejecuto para seleccionar el indice pero aun asi es demasiado lo que tarda

Comment: No se mucho como trabajas contra un dbf... pero estas asignando el indice a otro oledbcommand distinto.. puede ser???

Comment: ¿Cuánto se tarda la misma consulta si la haces por medio de Visual Fox Pro ?

Comment: Se tarda menos de 1 segundo, ya lo solucione, lo publicare en github por si alguno necesita una ayuda, intente usar el SDK de adminpaq pero la verdad es un dolor de cabeza